# connecting ros nxt by bluetooth

Tags: ros, nxt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can you use bluetooth to connect the nxt to the ros diamondback edition......
well in the tutorials, he uses the standard usb cable , but cant we do something with pybluez?????? it would be really conviient..

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59433/connecting-ros-nxt-by-bluetooth/) by [Autobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/4553/autobot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-03-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The nxt bluetooth implementation is horribly slow to the point of unuseable for closed loop control.  It will work using bluetooth but it can only do very slow interactions.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-08-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0